# appSettings not getting saved after Application Exit in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to save my appSettings using ConfigurationManager during run-time. I use the following code to update the key-value pair in configuration:

```
private bool SetAppConfigSetting(string Key, string Value)
{
    bool result = false;
    try
    {
        System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(Key);
        var kvElem = new KeyValueConfigurationElement(Key, Value);
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(kvElem);

        // Save the configuration file.
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

        // Force a reload of a changed section.
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

        result = true;
    }
    finally
    { }
    return result;
}
```

It removes the existing key-value pair and replaces it with new application settings every time I call it.

However, I see that the `appSettings` get updated in `Application.vshost.exe.config` only when my code is running, however as soon as the code hits `Application.Exit()`, the `appSettings` are all gone.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Tried with this modification, still does not work..

Comment: I found the issue. It was because I was building my code in Debug mode instead of release mode. When I changed my build mode to Release, I could see that the AppSettings got saved into Application.exe.Config file. Thanks!